# ADWS on Server 2003 Base

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

Got a hard one to deal with here.

I am trying to install web services on Server 2003 SP2 (x86/ base NOT R2!) but when I install it I am getting errors with the resulting Log:

```
0.031: ================================================================================
0.031: 2015/06/01 13:35:42.209 (local)
0.031: c:\b586c84e509a0cce78a3c624926d\update\update.exe (version 6.3.19.0)
0.031: Hotfix started with following command line: 
0.031: In Function GetReleaseSet, line 1193, RegQueryValueEx failed with error 0x2
0.031: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductType is Equal To Specified Value 
0.031: First Condition in Prereq.CheckIfAnyInstanceRunning.Section Succeeded
0.031: Condition succeeded for section Prereq.CheckIfAnyInstanceRunning.Section in Line 1 of PreRequisite 
0.031:  SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5 is Present 
0.031: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\SP is Less Than Specified Value 
0.031: Second Condition in Prereq.CheckCLR.Section Failed
0.031: Condition Check for Line 2 of PreRequisite returned FALSE 
0.031: ReadStringFromInf: UpdSpGetLineText failed: 0xe0000102
0.031: KB968934 Setup encountered an error:  Setup cannot continue because one or more prerequisites required to install KB968934 failed. For More details check the Log File c:\windows\KB968934.log
0.031: ReadStringFromInf: UpdSpGetLineText failed: 0xe0000102
0.031: Setup cannot continue because one or more prerequisites required to install KB968934 failed. For More details check the Log File c:\windows\KB968934.log
```

I checked updates, made sure .NET 3.5 was good and I can't seem to find a ref on here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the Prerequisites for the KB in mention?

Also upon a brief Bing Search I found this similar issue regarding installing AD Web Management Gateway on Server 2003 which may or may not be applicable to you.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ffeebdb-80a6-4435-8979-81d1430cd086/cannot-install-web-management-gateway-kb968934-on-windows-2003-sp2-enterprise?forum=winserverDS